# Convert Wordperfect to pdf using okular

Tags: pdf, okular, wordperfect

Okular --version 22.12.2 correctly displays some very old wordperfect documents, including all the math. But it won't save-as pdf, won't export-as at all, and won't print. Online converters such as https://www.zamzar.com/convert/wpd-to-pdf/ properly convert some, but not all, of the math. How can I get okular to save the file it's displaying as pdf?

The converters I tried didn't properly convert all the math. Only okular, using --version 22.12.2, seemed to properly display everything. But it will only save as .wp or .okular, not as .pdf. How can I get it to save-as .pdf?

**E d i t**
Found answer: Okular apparently isn't displaying the wpd document itself. Rather, it's using calligra to do the real work. So I tried directly using calligra, which of course displays exactly the same correct thing. Moreover, calligra has an Export-to-pdf which works just fine. Problem solved.